# Please help me to understand these error

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

float func (float t, float y){
    return y ;
}

int main (){
    float t0,y0,t,y;
    printf ("the value of t: ");
    scanf ("%f",&t0);
    printf ("the value of y: ");
    scanf ("%f",&y0);
    t=t0;
    y=y0;
    static int n=0;

    //     t[0]=t0;
    //     y[0]=y0;

    for (n=0;n<=3;n++){
        y[1]=y[0];
        printf ("value of y %f   %f \n",t,y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
Building prog.obj.
D:\master\c language\ch3\prog.c(166): warning #2117: Old-style function definition for 'main'.
D:\master\c language\ch3\prog.c(182): error #2144: Type error: pointer expected.
D:\master\c language\ch3\prog.c(182): error #2144: Type error: pointer expected.
*** Error code: 1 ***
```

Comment: `y` is a `float`. What do you expect that `y[1]=y[0]` should do??

Comment: Why y[1]=y[0]; ??????????? :You have not defined array.

Comment: What you are trying to do ?

Comment: iam begginer i want to solve this differential equation dy/dt= y as a simple example

Comment: Wellcome to SO. Please take the time looking into the help text on how to ask questions here. Actually yours isn't even a question. Cook your problem code down to a minimal example, and inspect the offending lines carefully. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

You cannot array index something that is not an array, or a pointer into an array.

Your `y` and `t` `float`s are not pointers into arrays in your program.

You should make them `float *y,  *t` into pointers so you can point them into array.

Change `float t0,y0,t,y;` to `float t0,y0,*t,*y;`

and

```
t=&t0; //assign address of t0 to t
y=&y0;
```

Change `printf ("value of y %f   %f \n",t,y);` to

```
  printf ("value of y %f   %f \n",*t,*y); //note to dereference t and y here, to get their values
```

[Here's a example of your program I fixed to work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d211bed27dbc86cf)

Answer (score 0):

The 'Old-style function definition for `main()`' message means that you've not given a prototype definition.  The correct forms are:

```
int main(void) { ... }
int main(int argc, char **argv) { ... }
```

The version `int main()` is fine in C++, but not strictly a prototype in C, and hence gets the 'old-style' tag.

The other messages are more inscrutable; the line numbers do not correspond to the code you show.  However, as [Tony The Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174614/tony-the-lion) notes in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21521538/15168), the line

```
y[1] = y[0];
```

is erroneous since `y` is not an array.  There is room to think that should be:

```
 y = y0;
```

and you'd need a companion:

```
 t = t0;
```

in order to have defined values printed in the `printf()` statement.

Even with these changes, the code does not make a lot of sense.  However, given that you removed 150-odd lines, we can suppose that the missing code would make more sense.

There is no need to make `n` into a `static` variable; it is better not to do so.

---

*Please make sure, in future, that your error messages correspond to the source code you post, not to some variant version of the code you post.  The line numbers should not be as large as 166 or 182; they should be single digit numbers or small double digit numbers. But even more importantly, they should match the code!*